# upload multiple documents with PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I am working on a user registration form in which the user is required to upload his profile image and a document for verification purposes. These are the two different fields in the form. The code works fine but the problem is that it only uploads the profile image and stores it in the verification documents folder. It does not upload the verification document. It works fine if I remove or comment one of the field.

Below is my controller function.

```
    /** UPLOAD PROFILE IMAGE **/

    $prof_pic = $_FILES['profile_pic']['name'];

    $config = array ('upload_path' => './images/tutors/',
                     'allowed_types' => "jpeg|jpg|png",
                     'overwrite' => TRUE
                    );

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->do_upload('profile_pic');


    /** UPLOAD VERIFICATION DOCUMENT **/

    $tut_ver_docs = $_FILES['tut_ver_docs']['name'];

    $new_config = array ('upload_path' => './emp_verification_documents/',
                         'allowed_types' => "jpeg|jpg|png",
                         'overwrite' => TRUE
                    );

    $this->load->library('upload', $new_config);
    $this->upload->do_upload('tut_ver_docs');
```

Comment: Where are the variables `$Maxtype` `$fname` and `$lname`?

Comment: $Maxtype, $fname and $lname are global variables in my file..they are not the issue.

Comment: If you're naming the files exactly the same they are.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

with :

```
$this->load->library('upload');
$this->upload->initialize($config);
```

Comment: Should I do the same with $this->load->library('upload', $new_config);

Comment: just add : $this->upload->initialize($new_config);

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
$this->load->library('upload', $new_config);
```

with

```
$this->upload->initialize($new_config);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why you're loading the upload class twice:

```
$this->load->library('upload');
$this->upload->upload_path = './images/tutors/';
$this->upload->allowed_types = array('jpeg','jpg','png');

foreach($_FILES as $name => $file){
    if($name == 'tut_ver_docs'){ //if its the verification document, change the upload path
        $this->upload->upload_path = './emp_verification_documents/';
    }
    if( ! $this->upload->do_upload($name){
        //catch error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not tested it But I think this should work for you

```
/** UPLOAD PROFILE IMAGE **/
$this->load->library('upload');//load the library

$config = array ('upload_path' => './images/tutors/',
                 'allowed_types' => "jpeg|jpg|png",
                 'overwrite' => TRUE
                );//config for profile picture
$this->upload->initialize($config);
if (!$this->upload->do_upload('profile_pic'))
{
   print_r($this->upload->display_errors());//upload fails.you can print the error or display somewhere else
}   


/** UPLOAD VERIFICATION DOCUMENT **/

$tut_ver_docs = $_FILES['tut_ver_docs']['name'];

$new_config = array ('upload_path' => './emp_verification_documents/',
                     'allowed_types' => "jpeg|jpg|png",
                     'overwrite' => TRUE
                );
$this->upload->initialize($new_config);
if (!$this->upload->do_upload('tut_ver_docs'))
{
   print_r($this->upload->display_errors());//upload fails
}
```